# How do I call an algebraic structure with two sets, one of which acts upon the others, but neither has a binary operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory

So I have these two sets $Nut$ and $Bag$, and an operation $(Nut \times Bag) \rightarrow Bag $. By analogy with a *group* of actions (such as a symmetric group of permutations of a set), I can call $Nut$ a *set* of actions upon $Bag$. What then do I call this whole structure?

Furthermore, if I have a *class of sets* that form a *directed graph* with respect to the relation "$A$ acts  upon $B$" as defined above, how do I call this graph and what branch of mathematics is involved with studying this kind of objects?

Comment: Careful with the word "action". If $Nut$ is a group (or monoid), then your action might not be a real action, since it doesn't have to satisfy $f\left(f\left(n,c\right),b\right) = f \left(n, cb\right)$.

Comment: A class of sets which forms a directed graph is very close to being a _category_. You might be able to steal some terminology from there.

Comment: If you don't specify any requirements of this "action" (and it is hard to specify much without putting additional structure on the sets), then everything acts on everything else, so I don't think it is useful to consider that relation.

Comment: I would just say that $Nut$ is a subset of the functions $Bag\to Bag$.

Comment: @rschwieb Except that with no further restrictions, the map from $Nut$ to those functions might not be injective.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft that's true, then maybe it could be described as an indexed family of such functions.